# seconds since midnight to datetime (python)

Tags: python, datetime

I have a timezone aware datetime date object:

```
Timestamp('2004-03-29 00:00:00-0456', tz='America/New_York')
```

and a number of mili seconds since midnight (midnight in the local timezone):

34188542

How to combine them to get a valid datetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object and add it to you time like this:

```
td = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=34188542)
date_object = datetime.datetime.now() + td  # change to your datetime object, I just use `now()`
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the datetime object is `ts`, and by "combine them", you mean "add them":

```
ms = 34188545
new_datetime = ts + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds = ms)
```